# Как сделать корректное добавление новых задач в массив tasks и динамическое обновление объектов массива на страницу HTML?

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener

Дано:

1. Дан HTML код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_14_HW.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Код к первому заданию -->
    <div id="tasks">
        <div class="tasks__wrapper">
          <form class="create-task-block">
            <input
              name="taskName"
              class="create-task-block__input default-text-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Создайте новую задачу"
              value="Посмотреть урок по JavaScript"
            >
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="create-task-block__button default-button"
            >
              Создать
            </button>
          </form>
          <div class="tasks-list">  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="js/index_14_HW.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. JS код в котором изначально идет отображение всех задач на HTML страницы через tasks.forEach()

```
const tasks = [ 
    {
        id: '1138465078061', 
        completed: false, 
        text: 'Посмотреть новый урок по JavaScript', 
    },
    {
        id: '1138465078062', 
        completed: false,
        text: 'Выполнить тест после урока', },
    {
        id: '1138465078063', 
        completed: false, 
        text: 'Выполнить ДЗ после урока', 
    },
]

const taskList = document.querySelector('.tasks-list');


//1 РЕШЕНИЕ 
//Функция для формирования input и label
const createInputWithLabel = (
    inputClass, inputType, inputId,
    ) => {
        const inputElement = document.createElement('input');
        inputElement.className = inputClass;
        inputElement.type = inputType;
        inputElement.id = inputId;
        
        return inputElement;
    };
 

//Перебор всех элементов 
tasks.forEach ((item) => {    

//DIV
const divOne = document.createElement('div');
        divOne.className = 'task-item';
        divOne.dataset.taskId = `${item.id}`;

const divTwo = document.createElement('div');
        divTwo.className = 'task-item__main-container';

const divThree = document.createElement('div');
        divThree.className = 'task-item__main-content';   
        
        
//Формирование INPUT и Label
const newInputOfLabel = createInputWithLabel (
    'checkbox-form__checkbox', "checkbox", `${item.id}`,
)
        
//Форма      
const form = document.createElement('form');
form.className = 'checkbox-form';

//label
const labelContainer = document.createElement('label');
      labelContainer.htmlFor = `${item.id}`;

//SPAN
const newSpan = document.createElement('span');
      newSpan.className = 'task-item__text';
      newSpan.innerText = `${item.text}`;


//Button
const newBaton = document.createElement('button');
      newBaton.className = 'task-item__delete-button';
      newBaton.dataset.deleteTaskId = `${item.id}`;
      newBaton.innerText = 'Удалить';


form.append(newInputOfLabel, labelContainer);
taskList.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', divOne);
divOne.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', divTwo);
divTwo.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', divThree);
divThree.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', form);
form.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newSpan);
divThree.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newBaton);

});
```

3. JS событие на форму, при нажатии на кнопку которого, формирует новые задачи и помещает их в массив tasks

```
const createTaksForm = document.querySelector('.create-task-block');
createTaksForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault(); //значение по умолчанию

    const { target } = event;
    const taskNameInput = target.taskName;
    const inputValue = taskNameInput.value;
    if(inputValue) {
        const newTask = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            text: inputValue,
        }
        tasks.push(newTask);
        taskList.append(newTask);
        console.log(newTask);
        console.log(tasks);
    }
});
```

По итогу новые задачи в массив tasks он формирует. Но динамическое отображение на страницы показывает [object Object]

[image: Скрин результата]

Comment: Вы в HTML элемент(список) пытаетесь добавить объект, который не является html элементом, поэтому он приводится к строке и добавляется в виде блока текста

Comment: Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Вы уже писали код создания html элемента задания в `tasks.forEach ((item) => {//...} `, перенесите его в функцию и используйте  и при инициализации списка и при добавлении задачи

Comment: Cпасибо за помощь . Решить получилось . Ответ добавил.

Comment: Это здорово. К сожалению, полноценный ответ, тогда у меня не было времени писать. Поставлю плюсик вам за ответ :-)  через три дня можете принять его как верный.

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

1. Убрали изначальный Foreach
2. Поместили всю созданную JS-ом верстку в отдельную функцию

```
const createTaskItem = (taskId, taskText) => {
   
//Функция для формирования input и label
const createInputWithLabel = (
    inputClass, inputType,
    ) => {
        const inputElement = document.createElement('input');
        inputElement.className = inputClass;
        inputElement.type = inputType;
        inputElement.id = `task-${taskId}`;
        
        return inputElement;
    };

    //DIV
const divOne = document.createElement('div');
divOne.className = 'task-item';
divOne.dataset.taskId = `task-${taskId}`;

const divTwo = document.createElement('div');
divTwo.className = 'task-item__main-container';

const divThree = document.createElement('div');
divThree.className = 'task-item__main-content';   


//Формирование INPUT и Label
const newInputOfLabel = createInputWithLabel (
'checkbox-form__checkbox', "checkbox",
)

//Форма      
const form = document.createElement('form');
form.className = 'checkbox-form';

//label
const labelContainer = document.createElement('label');
labelContainer.htmlFor = `task-${taskId}`;

//SPAN
const newSpan = document.createElement('span');
newSpan.className = 'task-item__text';
newSpan.innerText = taskText;


//Button
const newBaton = document.createElement('button');
newBaton.className = 'task-item__delete-button';
newBaton.dataset.deleteTaskId = `task-${taskId}`;
newBaton.innerText = 'Удалить';


form.append(newInputOfLabel, labelContainer);
taskList.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', divOne);
divOne.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', divTwo);
divTwo.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', divThree);
divThree.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', form);
form.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newSpan);
divThree.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newBaton);

return divOne;
};

tasks.forEach((item) => {
const taskItem = createTaskItem(item.id, item.text);
    console.log(taskItem);
// taskList.append(taskItem);
});
```

3. Прогнали  функцию createTaskItem через Foreach в объекте tasks

```
tasks.forEach((item) => {
const taskItem = createTaskItem(item.id, item.text);
    console.log(taskItem);
});
```

4. Создали событие, которое формирует новый объект и пушит его в объект tasks
5. Добавили новый объект через append ниже стартового объекта

```
//Создаем событие на форму
const createTaksForm = document.querySelector('.create-task-block');
createTaksForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault(); //значение по умолчанию

    const { target } = event;
    const taskNameInput = target.taskName;
    const inputValue = taskNameInput.value;
    if(inputValue) {
        const newTask = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            text: inputValue,
        }
        tasks.push(newTask);
        const taskItem = createTaskItem(newTask.id, newTask.text);
        console.log(taskItem);
        taskList.append(taskItem);
    }
});
```